# I have issue with commerce_order_load_multiple function

Tags: commerce

The way i am using this function is

```php
foreach ($mms as $mm) {
  $orders_of_user += commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => $mm->uid, 'status' => 'cart'));
}
```

But i am not getting anything output from this and when i use static value of integer in place of uid i am getting result..

```php
$orders_of_user += commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => 421, 'status' => 'cart'));
```

I don't understand what causing the problem in foreach

Answer (score 0):

> when i use static value of integer in place of uid i am getting result

Logically speaking, that can only mean that `$mm->uid` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Install the `devel` module and use the `dpm` function to inspect the var:

```
foreach ($mms as $mm) {
  dpm($mm);
}
```

That should tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi Clive, i have checked the $mm, the values are correct.

Comment: Then I'm afraid your question doesn't make sense - if you substitute `$mm->uid` for the static value that you've 100% determined is contained in that var, then it has to work or you have a broken/augmented version of php

Comment: Hi thanks for you comment. i got the problem it is because of one order problem in database. It is solved now.